# Implementing rich text feature in Angularjs with angular-smiles.min.js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am working on implementing rich texts for comments, bold, italic etc. I came across `angular-smiles` which is quiet easy and amazing to use.

```
<body ng-controller="SomeCtrl">

<p ng-bind-html="message | smilies "></p>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"
        smilies-selector="message"
        smilies-placement="right"
        smilies-title="Smilies"></span>
  <textarea ng-model="message" focus-on-change="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
```

I also have to implement other features like `**` to bold and keeping `line breaks` as `<br>` . Can someone please guide me on the angular way of doing it. A small hint with relevant topic is good enough to help me out as the project in hand has very limited time to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet will be `filters`. I would highly recommend you to go through it.

now, just to help you out, I have written down a small code to help you grab it better.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,FILTER_FUNCTIONS) {
  $scope.message = '';

   // remove this,just to show you line breaks
   $scope.$watch('message',function(newVal,oldVal){
    console.log(newVal)
   })
 });

 function f1(str){
   var obj = { expr: /\n+?/g, value: '<br>' };
   return str.replace(obj.expr, obj.value)
 };

function f2(str){
  var boldArray = str.split("**");
  console.log(boldArray)
  if(boldArray.length < 3){
     return str;
  }else{
    for(var count = 0 ; count < boldArray.length ; count++){
      if(count%2 !== 0 && (count+1 !== boldArray.length)){
       boldArray[count] = '<strong>'+boldArray[count]+'</strong>'
  }else if(count%2 !== 0){
    boldArray[count] = '**'+boldArray[count]
    }
  }
 return boldArray.join("");
 }
}

var arr = [f1,f2];

app.value('FILTER_FUNCTIONS',arr);

app.filter('richText', function(FILTER_FUNCTIONS) {
  return function(string) {
    return FILTER_FUNCTIONS.reduce(function(result, someFn) {
      return someFn(result);
    }, string || '');
  };
});
```

and in your html , add `message | smilies | richText`.

you can increase the rich text feature just by adding new functions in your array `arr`